# Make Firedac use a newer version of TLS

Tags: c++builder, firedac

I have a program written in C++Builder XE6. It uses a `TFDConnection` to connect to a remote MySQL database. Now the database has been upgraded (from 8.0.25 to 8.0.28), and refuses to let the program connect.

I understand it is because `TFDConnection` uses TLS v1, and the database now requires at least TLS v1.2. I have confirmed with Wireshark that my program tries to connect with TLS v1 and is rejected, while I can connect with MySQL Workbench, which uses TLS v1.3.

Does anyone know how I can make `TFDConnection` use a newer version of TLS than v1?

Comment: It is not FireDAC itself that uses TLS, but the underlying MySQL library that FireDAC uses internally. You should be able to provide up-to-date MySQL libraries and then set the configuration according to MySQL's documentation. See [Connect to MySQL Server (FireDAC)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)) in Embarcadero's documentation, and [Encrypted Connection TLS Protocols and Ciphers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html) in MySQL's documentation.

Comment: So, it is the version of libmysql.dll that controls the connection. Looked on MySQL's website, but not easy to find.
I had guessed it would be under Connector/C++, but couldn't find libmysdql.dll in that package.
The latest 32-bit version I found in the ZIP Archive for MySQL Community Server v5.7.41, and it allows me to connect using TLS v1.2. So for now it works!

Thanks Remy, you've been a blessing for this C++Builder community for many years!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Delphi 11.3 and TLS.  In my case, I can only get it to connect with TLS V 1.1  I have downloaded the latest versions of libmysql.dll and that forced a move from V1 to V1.1  As In Tomas's case Wireshark reports that my Host server can connect using TLS V1.3.  Any ideas on this or is the MYSQL component library for Delphi in need of a an update ??

Comment: For me it was just enough to use the version of libmysql.dll I found in the archive I mentioned. My application is written in XE6, a much older environment than yours. In some installations, we also had to install (update) the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package, which the newer libmysql required.